# Reduce PDA for a given language

Tags: automata, pushdown-automata

I drew a Push-down Automata, accepting the following language:
$$
\{ xcy : x,y \in (a+b)^*, \#_a(x) > \#_{bb}(y) \}.
$$
Here $\#_{bb}(y)$ counts the number of times that $bb$ appears in $y$, *with overlaps*. For example, $\#_{bb}(bbb) = 2$.

My question here. Is it possible to reduce my PDA to less states? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "reduce [...] to the same result?"

Comment: @Steven reduce the number of states (less than 4 states)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can obtain a PDA with only one state by "encodng" the state of your PDA into the stack of the new PDA. See [this document](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs381/2004fa/onestate.pdf).